# My cursor keeps switching when I paste in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VS code seems to be glitching because whenever I paste anything the cursor changes from the blinking '|' to the big box insert type cursor. Is this just a setting I can change?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed the VIM extension for VS Code?

If so, you can disable it or maybe change the key mapping, see here:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim